# How to cover a specific line in mockito in flutter?

Tags: flutter, mockito

```
String get manageCaregiverLabel => isCaregiverAssignedToPatient ||
          caregiverStatus != null && caregiverStatus!.contains('Pending')
      ? 'Caregiver: ${_nameShortenerService.abbreviateLastName(
          _caregiverService.caregiverInvitation?.name ?? '',
        )}'
      : _localizer.myAccountLandingScreen_inviteCaregiver;




 test(
        'manageCaregiverLabel returns correct value when caregiver is assigned',
        () {
      when(
        mockUserService.relatedUserSummary,
      ).thenReturn(caregiverMockSummary);

      when(mockCaregiverService.caregiverInvitation?.name).thenReturn(null);
      when(mockNameShortenerService.abbreviateLastName(any))
          .thenReturn('John D.');

      when(
        mockCaregiverService.getCaregiverStatus(
          testLocal,
        ),
      ).thenReturn('Pending');
      final result = viewModel.isCaregiverAssignedToPatient ||
              viewModel.caregiverStatus != null &&
                  viewModel.caregiverStatus!.contains('Pending')
          ? 'Caregiver: ${mockNameShortenerService.abbreviateLastName(
              mockCaregiverService.caregiverInvitation?.name ?? '',
            )}'
          : localizer.myAccountLandingScreen_inviteCaregiver;

      expect(viewModel.caregiverStatus, isNotNull);
      expect(viewModel.caregiverStatus, 'Pending');
      expect(result, viewModel.manageCaregiverLabel);
    });
  });
```

Here only this line is not covered

caregiverStatus != null && caregiverStatus!.contains('Pending')

Please help me cover this too in Mockito flutter. Other lines are showing covered. But only for this line it is not covered.

Answer (score 2):

In your provided code, it seems that you are trying to test the behavior of the manageCaregiverLabel method based on the conditions in your Dart code.

To test the specific line caregiverStatus != null && caregiverStatus!.contains('Pending'), you need to set up your mock objects and expectations accordingly. You can use the when and thenReturn methods from Mockito to control the behavior of your mocked objects.

Here's an example of how you can modify your test to cover the specific line:

```
test(
  'manageCaregiverLabel returns correct value when caregiverStatus is Pending',
  () {
    // Set up your mock objects and expected values
    when(mockUserService.relatedUserSummary).thenReturn(caregiverMockSummary);
    when(mockCaregiverService.caregiverInvitation?.name).thenReturn(null);
    when(mockNameShortenerService.abbreviateLastName(any)).thenReturn('John D.');
    when(mockCaregiverService.getCaregiverStatus(testLocal)).thenReturn('Pending');

    // Trigger the method under test
    final result = viewModel.manageCaregiverLabel;

    // Verify the expectations
    verify(mockUserService.relatedUserSummary).called(1); // adjust the number as needed
    verify(mockCaregiverService.caregiverInvitation?.name).called(1);
    verify(mockNameShortenerService.abbreviateLastName(any)).called(1);
    verify(mockCaregiverService.getCaregiverStatus(testLocal)).called(1);

    // Add your assertions for the specific line
    expect(viewModel.caregiverStatus, isNotNull);
    expect(viewModel.caregiverStatus, 'Pending');
    expect(
      result,
      'Caregiver: ${mockNameShortenerService.abbreviateLastName(mockCaregiverService.caregiverInvitation?.name ?? '')}',
    );
  },
);
```

Comment: did you use any generative AI at all in the writing of this answer post?